# Redshift Temp Table Identity column

Tags: amazon-redshift, temp-tables

My stored procedure includes the following code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #lala
(
     idx int IDENTITY(1,1), 
     tablename nvarchar(128)
);
  
INSERT INTO #lala(tablename)
    SELECT LEFT(tablename, LEN(tablename) - 3)
    FROM SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES 
    WHERE schemaname = 'spectrum' 
      AND tablename LIKE '%_v2';
```

I'm then calling it like this:

```
BEGIN;
CALL myschema.make_union_views('spectrum_views','spectrum','mycursor');
FETCH ALL FROM mycursor;
COMMIT;
```

At first it was running succesfully.

Then it began falling over, and debugging, I listed the contents of '#lala

[image]

I am confused as to how this has come about - that the [idx] column is not sequential ?

Hope that someone can shed some light on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Redshift is a cluster and as such communications between parts of the cluster are expensive.  Redshift ensures the uniqueness of identity columns but NOT sequentiality.  Per the CREATE TABLE documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html):

> When you load the table using an INSERT INTO [tablename] SELECT * FROM
> or COPY statement, the data is loaded in parallel and distributed to
> the node slices. To be sure that the identity values are unique,
> Amazon Redshift skips a number of values when creating the identity
> values.

Comment: Thanks.  I've created my sequential numbers uing wondows functions in the select instead now :)

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I don't know what you've done, but I would be concerned that solution will not scale.